# Numpy .T syntax for Python

Tags: python, reshape

```
a =np.ones((100,100))
a += a.T
a
```

I don't understand why there is some 3. in the matrix. Why are all the number is not 2.?

Comment: I get a matrix of twos... Probably you did something that is not fully equivalent with your question.

Comment: The displayed example is not exposing the problem you are describing.
Please update your question with "code" that is exposing the problem.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question. You might want to edit in your NumPy version though, to avoid confusing those with a more recent version.

Answer (score 2):

`a` and `a.T` are two views of the same data. In earlier NumPy versions, when you do

```
a += a.T
```

cell updates that occur earlier in the process may cause later addition operations to use the updated values instead of the original values. For example, as part of `a += a.T`, NumPy might perform `a[0, 99] += a[99, 0]` to update `a[0, 99]`, and then later perform `a[99, 0] += a[0, 99]` to update `a[99, 0]`, using the new value of 2 for `a[0, 99]` instead of the original value of 1.

[NumPy 1.13 changes the semantics](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/release.html#ufunc-behavior-for-overlapping-inputs), guaranteeing that the original values will be used, so you won't see this problem in updated versions of NumPy.